# How to override constructor with parameters and implement it in separate file

Tags: c++

I have a subclass of a class named Entity, and I wan't that subclass to override Entity's constructor, but calling Entity's constructor too. So I declare the constructor like this:

```
EntitySphere(GLuint shader):Entity(shader){
    //Code
}
```

But that method only works if I implement the function there, in the class definition (or I get a lot of errors). How can I achieve the same, but being able to implement the constructor in the .cpp file?

Comment: You can implement the constructor in the .cpp file (but put the class name in front of the constructor name: `EntitySphere::EntitySphere`), while also declaring it in the header: `EntitySphere(GLuint sphere);`

Comment: I wpould like to add that in the header file for`EntitySphere` you do not need to include the `Entity` header. Simply declare it as `Entity:Entity(GLuint shader)`. Will save a lot of time if `Entity` header changes but those changes are not effecting `EntitySphere`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement a constructor (or any method, for that matter) outside the class definition, you need to specify the name of the class before the method name:

```
EntitySphere::EntitySphere(GLuint shader): Entity(shader) {
  // ...
}
```

Notice the `EntitySphere::` part before the rest of the method.

Otherwise, the compiler doesn't know which method you're providing the definition for. (Maybe it could be allowed to guess, but what if it guessed wrong and associated that implementation with some other function in your program?)

Comment: Thanks!The problem is that doing that I got a lot of errors. But removing the :Entity(shader) from the declaration fixed it, and now it works.